# This logic statement is as short as possible

Tags: c#

The logic `if-else` statement, in the below class, is as short as c# will allow, or can this statement be even shorter?

The logic structure `?:` [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) is a short-cut in some circumstances but not for the below?

```
class Stats
{
    public int Total = 0;
    public int Missed = 0;
    public int Correct = 0;
    public int Accuracy = 0;

    void Update(Boolean correctKey)
    {
        //correctKey ? Correct++ : Missed++; //incorrect syntax for this situation as the ? operator is used to set a value
        if (correctKey==true) Correct++;  else  Missed++; //shortest c# syntax?
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to make it shorter anyway? It's more readable the way it is.

Comment: It's not a shortcut syntax for **everything involving if-else logic**. Why must people insist otherwise?

Comment: What's the motivation behind making it shorter? Why not make it easier to read? It won't run any faster just because it's shorter.

Comment: `if (correctKey) Correct++; else Missed++;` now that's even shorter! :P

Comment: @BoltClock I thought the question was explicit in saying that I realised "correctKey ? Correct++ : Missed++;" is not the correct syntax, but I was wondering if there was any other syntax for the if-else I presented. Any suggestions on edits to the question?

Comment: @CodyGray the motivation is that in the future if I see some code that uses and alternative to a _traditional_ if-else then I'll know what is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conditional operator is intended to be used with *assignments*, not as a generalized replacement for the `if`/`else` statements. This is because it produces a *result* (it is an expression), and that result is then assigned to something else.

For example, consider the following statement:

```
var a = x != null ? x : y;
```

This sets the value of variable `a` to object `x` if it is not null, or if it is, object `y`. The goal here is readability. Some programmers find it easier to read a statement with extremely common and straightforward logic like that one in a single line, rather than spread out into `if`/`else` blocks.

<sup>(This pattern is essentially anachronistic in C# now that we have the null-coalescing operator, but it serves as a good instructional case.)</sup>

Conversely, what you're trying to express here doesn't really work with the conditional operator since it doesn't have a result and is not performing an assignment.

In this case, I would say that an `if`/`else` block is your best choice. Note that *shorter* code does not necessarily produce *faster* code. In fact, in more cases than not, the compiler or the JITer will produce equivalent code that has identical performance. Don't (ab)use the conditional operator to try and make your code *faster*, only use it when it makes your code more clear and readable. If readability or expressiveness requires breaking something up into multiple lines, then there's nothing wrong with doing exactly that.

As other examples show, you can in fact mash the `if`/`else` blocks into a single line:

```
if (correctKey) Correct++; else Missed++;
```

But this also doesn't make the code run any faster, it just crams it all together. Like run-on sentences, this should be used judiciously where the meaning is unmistakable.

Answer (score 3):

The terniary operator won't work in the update statement since it alone constitutes an expression and needs to have the value assigned.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
if (correctKey) Correct++;  else  Missed++;
```

You can only use the conditional operator in a statement that actually emits a result, e.g.

```
var result = correctKey ? Correct++ : Missed++;
```

`result` would be the previous value of either `Correct` or `Missed` before it is incremented.

Comment: <pedant> it's the "**conditional operator**" (which is the only example of "a" ternary operator (3 operands), as compared to binary (2) or unary (1))</pedant>

Comment: FYI - result will NOT contain the incremented value of `Correct` or `Missed`.  `x++` will return the pre-incremented value.  If you want result to contain the post-incremented value, you need to use `++x` instead.

Comment: @psubsee2003: You are exactly right. I will amend my answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Hanskesting: LOL @ <pedant>. Thank you for pointing that out. I will update my statement accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Terniary operator can be used as either of the case based on your requirement.

Assume values are

```
correctKey = false;
Correct = 1;
Missed = 2;

tempVar = correctKey ? Correct++ : Missed++;  // Result: 2
```

OR

```
tempVar = correctKey ? ++Correct : ++Missed;  // Result: 3
```

### EDIT:

For both cases, values is been incrementing. Hence this statement can be written as follows too:-

```
tempVar = (correctKey ? Correct : Missed)+1;  // Result: 3
```

Comment: FYI - tempVar will NOT contain the incremented value of `Correct` or `Missed`.  `x++` will return the pre-incremented value.  If you want result to contain the post-incremented value, you need to use `++x` syntax instead.

Comment: @psubsee2003: You are right but it depends upon how the person is using. Thanks for pointing. I have updated the answer..

Comment: Thank you.  You didn't actually explicitly say what value would be returned, just wanted to make sure it was clear for someone looking at this in the future and wondering why it wasn't returning the correct value

Comment: @psubsee2003: Now i have updated with result and one more simplified statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
var temp = correctKey == true ? Correct++ : Missed++;
```

Comment: This will only work as part of an emission statement, e.g. `Console.WriteLine(correctKey == true ? Correct++ : Missed++);` and not as a plain update.

Comment: Wont work, because "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement and new object expressions can be used as a statement".

Comment: correction made - the [conditional operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.80).aspx) returns something and that is why it needs to be assigned to form a legit statement

Answer (score 1):

if(...)  checks if the statement in brackets is "true".
it's possible to write

```
 if(correctKey)
    Correct++;
 else
    Missed++;
```

for short statements like yours use:

```
correctKey == true ? Correct++ : Missed++;
```