# PerformancePoint Filter MDX Query with or conditions

Tags: filter, mdx, performancepoint

I am trying to mimic this filter functionality in a PerformancePoint MDX query filter, which is then connected to a scorecard.

```
SELECT 
[Dim Status Month].[MONTHS].MEMBERS ON COLUMNS,

FILTER ([Dim Project].[LOB].MEMBERS,

    (
    strtomember('[Dim Project].[PM Login].&[' + CUSTOMDATA() + ']')
    or
    strtomember('[Dim Project].[TM Login].&[' + CUSTOMDATA() + ']')
    or
    strtomember('[Dim Project].[PAL Login].&[' + CUSTOMDATA() + ']')
    or
    strtomember('[Dim Project].[DO Login].&[' + CUSTOMDATA() + ']')
    or
    strtomember('[Dim Project].[ED Login].&[' + CUSTOMDATA() + ']')

    )
) ON ROWS
FROM [GLOBALDELIVERYREPORTING]
```

`CustomerData()` being the current user name.

It works fine with single conditions such as:

```
strtomember('[Dim Project].[PAL Login].&[' + CUSTOMDATA() + ']')
```

I cannot figure out the syntax for using multiple conditions, even though they work fine when I run them directly against the cube.

So, I dropped Filter Text Here in the MDX Query window of filter, and grabbed the query from SQL profiler and this is what it ends up looking like:

```
WITH SET [7afbf0ad32e34820ab610fb5927a5f6e] AS HEAD({ StrToSet("Filter Text Here") }, 5001)
                        SELECT 
                        { 
                            IIF(COUNT([7afbf0ad32e34820ab610fb5927a5f6e])=0, { },
                            {(EXTRACT([7afbf0ad32e34820ab610fb5927a5f6e], [7afbf0ad32e34820ab610fb5927a5f6e](0)(0).Dimension) AS [7afbf0ad32e34820ab610fb5927a5f6eX]), 
                            (GENERATE(
                                [7afbf0ad32e34820ab610fb5927a5f6eX],
                                {
                                    { [7afbf0ad32e34820ab610fb5927a5f6eX].CURRENT.ITEM(0).PARENT, [7afbf0ad32e34820ab610fb5927a5f6eX].CURRENT.ITEM(0) }(0) 
                                }, 
                                ALL))})
                        }
                        DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_TYPE ON 0,
                        { } ON 1
                        FROM [GlobalDeliveryReporting]
```

Comment: Are you sure the data is correct when you think it works with `strtomember('[Dim Project].[PAL Login].&[' + CUSTOMDATA() + ']')` ?

Comment: Yes, data is correct, customdata is just the authenticated user name in the connection string

Comment: hmmm. I'm going home now but will have a look at this tomorrow. Lost track a little bit - what is the question we are now trying to answer?!

Comment: Laugh.  How to use multiple or conditions in a PerformancePoint (for SharePoint 2010) MDX query filter

Comment: Not sure how this second script you have included relates to the first. Even the first line! Why is it pulling the first 5001 members of the set `[7afbf0ad32e34820ab610fb5927a5f6e]` that it creates? Just a comment but PerformancePoint will not be around for ever - did you try using SSRS to solve this problem?

Comment: The first script was an example of what I wanted the PerformancePoint filter to do.  The PerformancePoint MDX filter query section doesn't allow you to just paste the entire query in.  The second example was the way that PerformancePoint builds the query and sends it to the cube.  Whatever you type in the MDX query section gets wrapped in a stringtoset function.  As for why 5001?  I have no idea, an automatic configuration on the part of PerformancePoint I guess.

Comment: Maybe this just required a `set` and PP then uses this script you pasted in to add the set to the final script's `WHERE` clause. I will add the notation for a simple set to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Does it allow you to move the filter to the `WHERE` clause?

```
SELECT 
  [Dim Status Month].[MONTHS].MEMBERS ON COLUMNS,
  [Dim Project].[LOB].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM [GLOBALDELIVERYREPORTING]
WHERE
   (
    strtomember('[Dim Project].[PM Login].&[' + CUSTOMDATA() + ']')
    ,strtomember('[Dim Project].[TM Login].&[' + CUSTOMDATA() + ']')
    ,strtomember('[Dim Project].[PAL Login].&[' + CUSTOMDATA() + ']')
    ,strtomember('[Dim Project].[DO Login].&[' + CUSTOMDATA() + ']')
    ,strtomember('[Dim Project].[ED Login].&[' + CUSTOMDATA() + ']')
   );
```

Try `EXISTS` function instead:

```
SELECT 
  [Dim Status Month].[MONTHS].MEMBERS ON COLUMNS
 ,Exists
  (
    [Dim Project].[LOB].MEMBERS
   ,{
      StrToMember('[Dim Project].[PM Login].&[' + CustomData() + ']')
     ,StrToMember('[Dim Project].[TM Login].&[' + CustomData() + ']')
     ,StrToMember('[Dim Project].[PAL Login].&[' + CustomData() + ']')
     ,StrToMember('[Dim Project].[DO Login].&[' + CustomData() + ']')
     ,StrToMember('[Dim Project].[ED Login].&[' + CustomData() + ']')
    }
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [GLOBALDELIVERYREPORTING];
```

Or if you are sure `FILTER` is working then try nesting your filters like this:

```
SELECT 
  [Dim Status Month].[MONTHS].MEMBERS ON COLUMNS
 ,Filter
  (
    Filter
    (
      Filter
      (
        Filter
        (
          Filter
          (
            [Dim Project].[LOB].MEMBERS
           ,StrToMember('[Dim Project].[PM Login].&[' + CustomData() + ']')
          ),
         ,StrToMember('[Dim Project].[TM Login].&[' + CustomData() + ']')
        )
       ,StrToMember('[Dim Project].[PAL Login].&[' + CustomData() + ']')
      )
     ,StrToMember('[Dim Project].[DO Login].&[' + CustomData() + ']')
    )
   ,StrToMember('[Dim Project].[ED Login].&[' + CustomData() + ']')
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [GLOBALDELIVERYREPORTING];
```

Maybe you just need a simple set notation like the following:

```
{
  StrToMember('[Dim Project].[PM Login].&[' + CustomData() + ']')
 ,StrToMember('[Dim Project].[TM Login].&[' + CustomData() + ']')
 ,StrToMember('[Dim Project].[PAL Login].&[' + CustomData() + ']')
 ,StrToMember('[Dim Project].[DO Login].&[' + CustomData() + ']')
 ,StrToMember('[Dim Project].[ED Login].&[' + CustomData() + ']')
}
```

Comment: It doesn't allow me to write the entire query, it is just applying the filter against the set returned for the scorecard.  I haven't been able to determine exactly how it applies the filter, such as whether it is used like the Filter() function or a Where clause. I have tried it by enclosing them in brackets, separated by commas, using or, etc...

Comment: I neglected to mention this is SharePoint 2010, I believe the PerformancePoint mdx filter in SharePoint 2013 allows for the entire query to be specified

Comment: @Aaron ok - let me play as I suspect there will be another approach

Comment: @whytheq - My 2 cents. I would suggest you to delete this answer as of now and undelete it back once you have one that works for Aaron. It's a time bomb for a downvote this way.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti (points don't matter: my most down-voted question that I will not delete: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644853/this-logic-statement-is-as-short-as-possible) + if you read the comments it was not my fault that this attempt is not valid.

Comment: Hahaha..SO is so full of egomaniacs who tend to think unidirectional. Your wish brother.

Comment: It wraps everything in the mdx query filter box in a strtomember function: WITH SET [7afbf0ad32e34820ab610fb5927a5f6e] AS HEAD({ StrToSet("Filter Text Here") }, 5001).  So, now I am just trying to get a filter that works within that constraint, because just using the full on select didn't seem to work

Comment: @Aaron please add the new script to your original post for us to look at

Comment: @Aaron - Could it be that there was another query running parallely on the server and you are giving us that script?

Comment: No, I grabbed that script directly from profiler when I ran created the filter.  I guess PerformancePoint just does weird things in the background...

Comment: Thanks for trying, but that just returned an empty set with the All member... I'm beginning to think its not possible at this point.

Comment: In the end,  I went with a cascading set of filters, which provide a decent amount of filtering even if it isn't the functionality I wanted.  Thanks for all the help!